# Domain randomly becomes unresolved

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ssh, domain

Recently, I've been having some issues with a domain name. I set up my domain to point to my server, but every now and then, when attempting to ssh in, I get the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname {URL}: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

It isn't consistent, though, and I can't figure what actually causes it to suddenly throw the error. At one point, I was using an SFTP client to manage some server files, and it dropped mid-connection. Then, later, I was using Sequel Pro to connect to my database, and after I closed to connection in SQL Pro, it began throwing the error again.

Attempting to ping the domain returns:

```
ping: cannot resolve {URL}: Unknown host
```

But navigating to the domain in a browser has no issues -- loads it up just fine.

If anyone has any insight into what may be happening here, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the nameservers you are using? If there is more than one, try querying each of them with the host name in question: `dig example.com @ns1.yourprovider.com`